# как лучше удалить поля из таблицы в несколько терабайт используя mysql. alter table не справится

Tags: mysql

как лучше удалить поля из таблицы в несколько терабайт используя mysql. alter table не справится...

Comment: Лучше не удалять, всяко надолго. Но если упёрлось - лучше копируй то, что надо оставить, в новую таблицу.

Comment: нет, удалять придется, alter table для удаления не нужным мне полей использовать я не могу...

Comment: Ну тогда CREATE - INSERT .. SELECT - DROP - RENAME.

Comment: это не вариант... моя цель ни создать, ни вставить ни удалить полностью, ни переименовать... а удалить часть полей, для экономии места на диске

Comment: Я не могу сделать как хочу, и не хочу как могу... ну тогда сиди и смотри.